# Emoji name "family_mothers_one_boy" or "woman-woman-boy"?

Tags: php, emoji, emoticons

I have a reference emojis file used by my php code. Inside there is for example "woman-woman-boy", but the browser (chrome) replaces this name by "family_mothers_one_boy"...

- Why are there two versions of emojis' names?
- Is there en (some) error(s) in my file, or should I have to do something in my code to avoid the conversion?

**NOTE:**
The code related to this emoji is:

```
1F469;&#x200D;&#x1F469;&#x200D;&#x1F466
```

Here are the two functions I'm using to manage the emojis:

1. When I display the emoji, I replace the tage :name: by the HTML rendering (using unicode)

```
    function replaceEmojiNameByUnicode($inputText){
    $emoji_unicode = getTabEmojiUnicode();
    preg_match_all("/:([a-zA-Z0-9'_+-]+):/", $inputText, $emojis);
    foreach ($emojis[1] as $emojiname) {
        if (isset($emoji_unicode[$emojiname])) {
            $inputText = str_replace(":".$emojiname.":", "&#x".$emoji_unicode[$emojiname].";", $inputText);
        }
        else { 
            $inputText = str_replace(":".$emojiname.":", "(:".$emojiname.":)", $inputText);

        }
    }
    return $inputText;
}
```

2. When I want to propose the list of emoji I display an HTML SELECT in the page. Teh following function return the list of option to add inside:

```
/* Display the options in the HTML select */
function displayEmojisOptions(){
    $emoji_unicode = getTabEmojiUnicode();
    foreach ($emoji_unicode as $name => $unicode) {
        echo '<option value="&#x'.$unicode.';">'.$name.' =>  &#x'.$unicode.';</option>';
    }
}
```

3. In the array $emoji_unicode there is one entry (with 3 semi-column removed to not display emoji here):

   'family_one_girl' => '1F468;&#x200D&#x1F469&#x200D&#x1F467',

For example: In order to make it works, I have to replace the line **'thinking_face' => '1F914',** by **'thinking' => '1F914',**

My question is: why ??

Thank you

Comment: Well you can have a variable named `dog` and store a cat () in it, so please create a [mre], for example using a code snippet.

Comment: Every implementation (software that parses/displays the emoji's) can call them what ever they want. As long as they all show the same icon (or at least an icon that contains the same thing), does it really matter what they call it?

Comment: I did it, I add my code + an example value... thank you

Comment: Then I add a clear question !

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting a string like `this is my :family_mothers_one_boy: and I am :thinking: about them` from somewhere? If so, I don't think that's "the browser (Chrome)" that's giving you that string, it's some particular piece of code, probably a JavaScript editor like TinyMCE, CKEditor, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nop, the emoji text was changed by no code... I guess it was due to a wrong emoji file I used... I correct all the emoji manually and now I did not see the mismatch anymore...
If someone need the corrected file, I can provide it.